# SQL - Set marker for special data-constellations

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need some SQL advice here...

I've got a table with an object (called "entityid") , an updated timestamp and a status of that object.
I now want to track, how often that object was set "inactive" by the user. But it should only count max. 1x inactive per day. If the status before was also inactive, it should not count!

So here's a little example i prepared in Excel to show where the marker should appear and where not:

[image]

Do you have any advice how I can solve this by using SQL ? (We're currently working with Redshift -> PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions.  This returns the first "inactive" on each day:

```
select t.*,
       (content_status = 'inactive' and
        row_number() over (partition by entityid, updated_at::date, content_status) = 1
       ) as needed_marker            
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions.  This returns the first "inactive" on each day:

```
select t.*,
       (content_status = 'inactive' and
        row_number() over (partition by entityid, updated_at::date, content_status order by lastmodifiedtimestamp) = 1
       ) as needed_marker            
from t;
```

Note:  I'm not sure if `updated_at` is just the date.  If it is, then the logic is more like:

```
select t.*,
       (content_status = 'inactive' and
        row_number() over (partition by entityid, updated_at, content_status order by lastmodifiedtimestamp) = 1
       ) as needed_marker            
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want the first time that the status changes from active to inactive, then:

```
select t.*,
       (content_status = 'inactive' and
        num_actives = 1 and
        prev_status = 'active'
       ) as needed_marker            
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by entityid, updated_at order by lastmodifiedtimestamp) as num_actives,
             lag(content_status) over (partition by entityid, updated_at lastmodifiedtimestamp) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t;
```

Actually, the subquery is not needed:

```
select t.*,
       (content_status = 'inactive' and
        sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by entityid, updated_at order by lastmodifiedtimestamp) = 1 and
        lag(content_status) over (partition by entityid, updated_at lastmodifiedtimestamp) = 'active'
       ) as needed_marker 
from t;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, thats an interesting way to write SQL, never saw that before but it works. What that statement doesn't cover atm is the fact, that if the last entry the day before was also "inactive" it shouldn't count because there was no change to the status. Thank you very much for your effort!